# How to add a vertical line when using a log scale?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How does one add a vertical line to a `ggplot` plot that uses a log scale on the vertical axis?

For example,

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=1:2, y=c(10,20)), aes(x,y)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1.5)
```

works as expected. If one transforms the vertical axis to a log scale:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=1:2, y=c(10,20)), aes(x,y)) +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1.5) + 
  coord_trans(y = 'log')
```

then the vertical line disappears. Perhaps relevant is that if one changes the data slightly:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=1:2, y=c(1,20)), aes(x,y)) + # y[1] is now different
  geom_line() + 
  geom_vline(xintercept = 1.5) + 
  coord_trans(y = 'log')
```

then the vertical line is still missing, but a warning message is issued:

```
Warning messages:
1: In self$trans$y$transform(y) : NaNs produced
2: In trans$transform(value) : NaNs produced
```

So it's possible that the missing line is caused by trying to take logs of 0 (-Inf and no warning) or negative numbers (NaN and a warning).

(`sessionInfo()` gives `R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)` and `ggplot2_2.2.0`.)

Comment: It may be related to this (closed, but not fixed) issue: [geom_h/vline draws incomplete or no lines with coord_trans()](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/895)

Comment: [This has been a known problem for a long time](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ggplot2/FGbhwyfkc74).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your hunch is correct, that the problem is that geom_vline is trying to take a log of zero for the intercept.  You can instead use, geom_line, to draw a line segment that does not cross zero.

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=1:2, y=c(10,20)), aes(x,y)) +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_line(aes(x=c(1.5,1.5), y=c(0.1,200))) + 
  coord_trans(y = 'log', limy = c(10,20))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Do you think this should be reported as a `ggplot` bug?

Comment: Any Ideas on how to do it with a discrete x axis and parametrized y-limits?

Comment: @TobiO - I don't fully understand your question.  If the curent answer does not work for you, can I suggest asking a new question in which you provide a *reproducible example* of your "axis and parametrized y-limits".  You can link back to this question to explain why your issue is different.

Comment: I ran into multiple problems, when I had a discrete x-axis and a log-scale y-axis. I found out later, that the order in which the geoms are written matters. If the vline should go to the bottom, preceding it with `geom_blank()` helps. I found this tip somewhere on SO but now can't find the answer to link it here